# How to embed a route resource in a Devise route in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Under normal circumstances if one wants to embed resources within other resources in Ruby on Rails in the `routes.rb` file it would look like this:

```
# routes.rb

resources :parents do
  resources :children
end
```

The above will allow for a url like http://localhost:3000/parents/1/children.

My question is how to achieve the same result with the default `devise_for :parents` that exists in my `routes.rb` file?

I tried:

```
# routes.rb

devise_for :parents do
  resources :children
end
```

and it did not work properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [I found the answer in a previous report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712947/nested-resources-in-devise)

Comment: Can you add a detailed answer as an answer? That can help a lot of people since this specifically says Devise instead of normal routes, though answer will be more or less the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`devise_for` only creates the routes related to signing up and in, so you would still use

```
resources :parents do 
  resources :children
 end
```

in your routes for nested resource paths. There is a detailed answer here: [Nested Resource with Devise - Rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785684/nested-resource-with-devise-rails3)

If you generate the Devise controllers and views, you also need to specify those in your routes like this

```
  devise_for :parents, controllers: {
    sessions: 'parents/sessions',
    registrations: 'parents/registrations'
  }
```